# ALTER TABLE to add ON DELETE CASCADE statement

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, cascade, cascading-deletes, postgresql-9.0

I want to do the following in PostgreSQL (using Hibernate):

```
 ALTER TABLE fruits ADD CONSTRAINTS id ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Obviously, my code above is not working, so I am looking for the correct statement.

If I can't do that, then how about the following:

I have a bunch of data in my table `fruits`. The `id` field in `fruits` is used as a foreign key by table `grapes`. I need to delete a specific row in `fruits` and I want the deletion to cascade to `grapes` and delete all entries in `grapes` that has the specified `id`. How do I do that?

```
delete from fruits where id = 1 cascade;
```

NOTE: I don't want to do a join and delete the corresponding data in `grape`. This is just an example. In the real application a large number of tables depend on `fruits`.

Since I am using Hibernate, for the case when I use a delete statement, can hibernate help do it?
Or can I do this with the information schema or system catalog in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
    //in Fruit object
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fruit", orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Grape> grapes;

   //in Grape object
   @OneToOne
   private Fruit fruit;
```

Answer (score 5):

What you describe is the textbook [**foreign key constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) using the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.

In **SQL** you can create it implicitly when creating the table `grapes` in your scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE grapes (
  grape_id int PRIMARY KEY
  fruit_id int REFERENCES fruits(fruit_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```

Or you can add it later:

```
ALTER TABLE grapes
ADD CONSTRAINT grapes_fruit_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (fruit_id)
REFERENCES fruits (fruit_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Never edit system catalogs directly for that. Use the dedicated  [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) command.

Be aware that a foreign key constraint requires a unique or primary index on the referenced column (`fruits.fruit_id` in your case) and enforces [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).

Answer (score 1):

This is a unidirectional parent-child relationship, where you want a change at the parent to cascade down to the child, but not vice versa.  Using annotations, we can accomplish this.  In the `fruits` entity:

```
@Cascade(value = { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL, 
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fruit")
public Set<Grape> getGrapes() {
    return grapes;
}
```

In the 'grape' entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fruit_id")
public Fruit getFruit() {
    return fruit;
}
```

When you update or delete the parent `fruit`, the change will automatically cascade to the `grape` children.

Comment: in the Fruit POJO do I have to create a field `grapes` like `private Set<Grape> grapes;` with no annotation? Also same for the child concerning the parent?

Comment: Yes.  The above is annotations on the getters; you still need the fields

Comment: I try to do a lot on my own before coming back, just to see if there is a version of your post that might work. But it has not worked. First it complains about `Could not determin type for:java.util.Set, at table: Fruit,for column(grapes)`; then when I add `@ManyToOne` to the `Set<Grape> grapes` field, it says missing table Fruit_Grape. Still thanks for posting.

Comment: Post your entity code.  It appears that you are missing some things.

Answer (score 0):

**Motivation**

This did not work for me, I set

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

and the output did not state anything like `...ON DELETE CASCADE...`.

I found another solution which worked for me:

Lets assume you have a class for authors and a class for the author's books and you want to auto delete all books whenever you delete the author (via hibernate, sql-query, ...) and there's reasons you cannot (always) delete via session.delete().

Maybe:

```
session.createSQLQuery("DELETE FROM author").executeUpdate();
```

---

**Solution**

So your author class may look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Integer id;

   @Column(name = "NAME")
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
   private Set<Book> books;
...
```

and the class book looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Integer id;

   @Column(name = "TITLE")
   private String title;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_BOOK_author_AUTHOR_ID"))
   private Author author;
...
```

The trick is to name the foreign key constraints on your own using

```
foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_BOOK_author_AUTHOR_ID")
```

and then add

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">update.sql</property>
```

to your *hibernate.cfg.xml* (dont forget *hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto*). The *update.sql* then contains the update of the table constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE `book` DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_BOOK_author_AUTHOR_ID`; 
ALTER TABLE `book` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_BOOK_author_AUTHOR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AUTHOR_ID`) REFERENCES `author`(`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

So hibernate is always able to drop/change the constraints because it knows the name of the constraints - you should also check the @Cascade settings - and you have to implement a strategy on how you handle the deletion of the objects in your session!