# Stack Depth Limit exceeded in PostgresQL (After Delete Trigger)

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
   parent_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE child (
   parent_id VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES parent ON DELETE CASCADE,
   child_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_parent()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM parent WHERE parent_id = OLD.parent_id;
    RETURN NULL;
END; $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER delete_parent AFTER DELETE
ON child 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_parent();
```

Error:

`stack depth limit exceeded`
hint: 'Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 6144kB), after ensuring the platform\'s stack depth limit is adequate.'

Background:

- A `parent` can have many `children`
- The schema is designed to so that if a `parent` is deleted, all of its children records are also removed.
- If a `child` is deleted, the trigger deletes the `parent`, and then cascade deletes all the other `children` related to that `parent`

This has worked for months and today suddenly we started getting this error.

I can't find while there might be an infinite recursion and I am considering doubling the stack depth limit just to see what happens.

Note: The actual schema is more complex than this and has a few more related tables that have CASCADE delete constraints. But this is the only trigger.

**UPDATE**: So I doubled the max_stack_depth limit and now it is fine. I don't think this is a good solution and I am still unsure how I can for example prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: A cascading delete via the child->parent FK will result in all children getting deleted if a parent is deleted. Your trigger does the opposite. So once a kid is deleted, its parent **and its siblings** are deleted. Is this your intention?

Comment: That is right. If a child is deleted, delete the parent as well as all its silbings

Comment: BTW: why do you use varchar(255) fields as PK and FK ?

Comment: It is not actually VARCHAR(255). The server is on fire right now so I just quickly wrote a contrieved example instead of copying the real schema. It is a UUID.

Answer (score 2):

So far you that's what happens:

1. Delete child1.
2. Triggers deletion of parent.
3. Deletes ***`n`*** siblings of child1 by `DELETE CASCADE`.
4. Calls same trigger ***`n`*** times.
5. No more siblings left.

No endless loop, but still ***`n`*** invocations of the trigger. That could explain why your stack depth limit was exceeded, but you could fix it by increasing the limit. The same could happen again with a greater `n`.

As an alternative, replace your trigger with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_family()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM child  WHERE parent_id = OLD.parent_id;
    DELETE FROM parent WHERE parent_id = OLD.parent_id;  -- done after 1st call
    RETURN NULL;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;  -- don't quote the language name!

CREATE TRIGGER delete_family
AFTER DELETE ON child 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_family();
```

And replace the FK constraint with a version ***without*** `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Code example:

- [ALTER TABLE to add ON DELETE CASCADE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532711/alter-table-to-add-on-delete-cascade-statement/11583409#11583409)

Now, to `DELETE` a whole family, you can't delete the parent like before (now forbidden by FK). Instead `DELETE` any child.

Should be faster, too.

Comment: Hi @erwin thanks for the solution. It seems like the only thing the changed was the addition of `DELETE FROM child  WHERE parent_id = OLD.parent_id; `

Why does that reduce the number of invocations?

Comment: Also, when a parent is deleted it cascades to the child, and the child deletion triggers to try to delete the parent again (which at that point no longer exists)

Comment: @samol: Sorry, I forgot to add the essential detail: Drop `ON DELETE CASCADE` from the FK constraint.

Comment: But I will need the on delete cascade trigger, because sometimes I delete the parent and I need that delete to cascade

Comment: @samol: You *could* drop any child instead for the same effect. Also, I am not entirely sure your problem wasn't caused by additional triggers / constraints you mentioned.